# Bizarre result in frequent crashes in Xcode 8 with Swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3

I am getting frequent crashes in Xcode which would destroy some recent editing changes. They were small enough that I gritted my teeth and kept going. I encountered a bizarre situation, where Xcode crashed, came up and crashed again. This time it restored a much older version. I had not committed the changes.

Has anyone encountered frequent crashes? I logged this with apple and they suggested I send them a copy of my source code.

I have pods which load Firebase. I also use Json files stored and retrieved from the document directory and the bundle. The crashes are getting more and more frequent.

Is there a way I can turn off the Swift compiler when I am making significant changes?

Comment: Xcode 8 crashes very often for me too, but it doesn't destroy any of my code - I certainly wouldn't accept that! You should send a detailed bug report to Apple, this is not ok.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I agree. I plan to do it and will post the results.